# Is it possible to play the video until the bytes received while fetching the remaining contents from s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I need to play the video until the content received while fetching the remaining from s3 bucket.Similar to you tube i need to do this.If it possible what would help me to do in python.Provide me with samples

Comment: **Not clear**... What does _"...Similar to Youtube"_ actually mean here? Youtube plays MP4 and WebM videos in HTML5 using a `<video>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube and all the streaming media companies process and store the videos in Adaptive Bitrate Streaming formats like DASH or HLS. You can also attempt to do this when you create an MP4 file with qt_fast_start option in ffmpeg. You can play such videos while download is in progress.

Comment: Can anyone explain in more detailed way